# Creating an instance of a specialized class depending on run-time arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the code which demonstrates the idea:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Specific
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

    void DoSomething() {}
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Specific<T1, T2> create_specific()
{
    return Specific<T1, T2>();
}

void my_func(int type1, int type2)
{
    if (type1 == 1 && type2 == 1)
    {
        auto specific = create_specific<A, A>();
        specific.DoSomething();
    }
    else if (type1 == 1 && type2 == 2)
    {
        auto specific = create_specific<A, B>();
        specific.DoSomething();
    }
    else if (type1 == 2 && type2 == 1)
    {
        auto specific = create_specific<B, A>();
        specific.DoSomething();
    }
    else if (type1 == 2 && type2 == 2)
    {
        auto specific = create_specific<B, B>();
        specific.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

So `my_func` arguments control which type it will use to `DoSomething`.
The problem with this approach is that the number of if conditions will grow exponentially. I'm looking for a way to have the compiler do this for me. It would be nice if I could split the logic for every type slot:

```
if (type1 == 1) 
{
   create_specific1<A>(...);
}
....
if (type2 == 2) 
{
   create_specific2<B>(...);
}
```

Is it at all possible?

**UPDATE**

Is there any way to implement the template magic in C++11, in particular in Visual C++ 2013?

Comment: Why not using a common base class and storing pointers to that base?

Comment: You can do that. But the instantiation still happens at compile time only.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a lookup table like this.

```
void (*arr[2][2])() =
{
   [] { create_specific<A, A>().DoSomething(); },
   [] { create_specific<A, B>().DoSomething(); },
   [] { create_specific<B, A>().DoSomething(); },
   [] { create_specific<B, B>().DoSomething(); }
};

arr[type1-1][type2-1]();
```

You can also let the compiler produce it for you. This works with two types:

```
template <std::size_t...> struct index_list {using type = index_list;};

template <typename, typename> struct concat;
template <std::size_t... i, std::size_t... j> struct concat<index_list<i...>, index_list<j...>> : index_list<i..., j...> {};

// inefficient linear recursive method:
template <std::size_t N>
struct make_index_list : concat<typename make_index_list<N-1>::type, index_list<N>> {};
template <>
struct make_index_list<0> : index_list<0> {};

template <typename A, typename B = A,
          typename = typename make_index_list<std::tuple_size<A>::value
                                            * std::tuple_size<B>::value - 1>::type>
class create_lookup;

template <typename ... First, typename... Second, std::size_t... indices>
class create_lookup<std::tuple<First...>, std::tuple<Second...>, index_list<indices...>>
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    static void work()
    {
        create_specific<T, U>().DoSomething();
    }

public:

    static constexpr void (*arr[sizeof...(First)][sizeof...(Second)])() =
    {
        work< typename std::tuple_element<indices / sizeof...(First), std::tuple<First...>>::type,
              typename std::tuple_element<indices % sizeof...(Second), std::tuple<Second...>>::type >...
    };
};

template <typename ... F, typename... S, std::size_t... I>
constexpr void (*create_lookup<std::tuple<F...>, std::tuple<S...>, index_list<I...>>::arr[sizeof...(F)][sizeof...(S)])();

int main()
{
    auto arr = create_lookup<std::tuple<A, B>>::arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ": ";
        arr[i][j]();
    }
}
```

Since C++14 you could also use a lambda as the expansion pattern, instead of a function template (`work`). And [`std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), and `std::tuple_element_t` ... ;)

Setting the `DoSomething`-function to

```
void DoSomething()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T1).name() << ' ' << typeid(T2).name() << '\n';
}
```

yields the following output:

```
0 0: A A
0 1: A B
1 0: B A
1 1: B B
```

---

### Generazalization to more types

This code works with an arbitrary amount of concatenations, specified by the template parameter `depth`. Example is included, using GCC's demangle function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template<typename... T>
struct Specific
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        int status;
        std::initializer_list<bool> { std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status) << ' '... };
        //std::initializer_list<bool> { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ' '... };
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

template<typename... T>
Specific<T...> create_specific()
{ return {}; }

template <std::size_t...> struct index_list {using type = index_list;};

template <typename, typename> struct concat;
template <std::size_t... i, std::size_t... j> struct concat<index_list<i...>, index_list<j...>> : index_list<i..., j...> {};

template <std::size_t N>
struct make_index_list : concat<typename make_index_list<N-1>::type, index_list<N>> {};
template <>
struct make_index_list<0> : index_list<0> {};

constexpr std::uintmax_t ipow( std::uintmax_t base, unsigned exp )
{
    return exp == 0? 1 : base*ipow(base, exp-1);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t len, std::size_t dim>
struct construct_array
{
    using type = typename construct_array<T, len, dim-1>::type[len];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t len>
struct construct_array<T, len, 1>
{
    using type = T[len];
};

template <std::size_t depth,
          typename A,
          typename = typename make_index_list<ipow(std::tuple_size<A>::value, depth)- 1>::type>
class create_lookup;

template <std::size_t depth, typename ... First, std::size_t... indices>
class create_lookup<depth, std::tuple<First...>, index_list<indices...>>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    static void work()
    {
        create_specific<Args...>().DoSomething();
    }

    static constexpr auto length = sizeof...(First);

    template <std::size_t index, typename = typename make_index_list<depth-1>::type>
    struct get_ptr;

    template <std::size_t index, std::size_t ... type_indices>
    struct get_ptr<index, index_list<type_indices...>>
    {
        static constexpr auto value =
        work< typename std::tuple_element<index / ipow(length, depth-type_indices-1) % length, std::tuple<First...>>::type... >;
    };

public:

    static constexpr typename construct_array<void(*)(), length, depth>::type arr
    {
        get_ptr<indices>::value...
    };
};

template <std::size_t depth, typename ... F, std::size_t... I>
constexpr typename construct_array<void(*)(), create_lookup<depth, std::tuple<F...>, index_list<I...>>::length, depth>::type
    create_lookup<depth, std::tuple<F...>, index_list<I...>>::arr;

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

int main()
{
    auto arr = create_lookup<3, std::tuple<A, B, C>>::arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k << ": ";
        arr[i][j][k]();
    }
}
```

The same code but without `constexpr` can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c53c3be786930b).

Comment: Bonus points now for letting the compiler create that table ;)

Comment: @dyp Done. How does it look like?

Comment: Nice; I'm currently trying to [find a general way for N types instead of 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76440e3b7c500d9e)

Comment: Actually I also need this for several types rather than two. I used two types to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: @Max Do you mean the concatenation of more than two types or *using* more than two types (like, `A`, `B` and `C`)?

Comment: @Loopunroller It's both actually. In reality every slot should have a type from a separate list. And there will be several slot. 5 or more. Besides types there will be integers. So doing this by hand is too tedious.

Comment: @Max Hmmm even if I remove the (unsupported) C++14 features, it still does not compile. But I think that's a bug in VS. Could you try [this](http://rextester.com/RZUIO23377) with the latest VS Update?

Comment: @Max Appended a more general version to my post, does it work for you? Works for me with MinGW GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: @Loopunroller. No, it doesn't. Sorry. `constexpr` is not supported in VC++2013. I see that I need to install VC++ 2013 November CTP to have support for constexpr. I'll do that try again.

Comment: @Max You do realize that `constexpr` isn't actually needed here? It's just used for convenience, so you don't have to initialize the static data members outside class. And you can redefine the `ipow`-function with class templates.

Comment: @Max Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c53c3be786930b) work? Removed all the `constexpr`s.

Comment: I tried removing `constexpr` and it didn't work. It was complaining about volatile values, where it expected constants.

Comment: @Loopunroller No it doesn't. Sorry. I get `'N' : invalid template argument for 'make_index_list', expected compile-time constant expression`

Comment: @Max I see. Well, it seems like you have no choice but to move to a newer version of VC++. The one you're using atm  doesn't seem to handle constant expressions properly.